# OpenGL - C++: Free Camera in Opengl Development Cookbook

Tags: c++, opengl, mouse, glut

Recently reviewed in the following code that make use of the camera to FPS style.

[Code, function: OnMouseMove](https://github.com/josseline06/opengl33_dev_cookbook_2013/blob/master/Chapter2/FreeCamera/FreeCamera/main.cpp)

When capturing mouse movements and calculate the difference between the old movement and the new divide the result by 5 and then insert the new mouse coordinates in an array so that we can implement Mouse Filtering Smooth. My question is, why when calculating the difference between the mouse coordinates divided by 5?

Answer (score 1):

Since they're dividing everything by 5, it looks like this is simply a scaling factor that made the movement have the desired speed.   It was probably just empirical tweaking of this factor.